# Summary of data by Date

Tags: date, summary, frequency-analysis

lets say i have the following table
date        userid product cost
01-01-2017  21a mobile  200
02-02-2017  22b tv  1000
03-03-2017  23c sofa    250
04-03-2017  22b washingmachine  400

How do i arrive at some of the basic calculation
1. unique user per day per product
2. amount spent by product and by day

Comment: What software are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following database structure:

```
create table spent (
 day date,
 userid char ( 10 ),
 product char( 50 ), 
 amount decimal( 10, 2 ));
```

unique user per day per product:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(userid), day, product FROM spent GROUP BY day, product
```

the amount spent per product on each day

```
SELECT SUM( amount ), product, day FROM spent GROUP BY product, day
```

Depends that I understand your question correctly. Be aware that the selects do not contain any WHERE clause.